# pyodbc cursor.columns() bad argument type for built-in operation

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm trying to return the column names of a table using python. I was following the guide here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Cursor.wiki

```
for row in cursor.columns(table='Customers'):
    print(row.column_name)
```

This gives an error of the following:
"for row in cursor.columns(table='Customers'):
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation"

I'm able to connect to the database and the table just not with the cursor.columns. For example, this works:

```
for row in cursor.tables(table='Customers'):
    print(row.table_cat)
    print(row.table_type)
    print(row.table_name)
```

Comment: Your `for row in cursor.columns(table='Customers'): …` code works for me with pyodbc 4.0.31 and ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. What ODBC driver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This worked well for me:

```
for col in cur.columns(table='Bearings'):
    print(col[3])
```

It turns out that `cur.columns` is a list of tuples, and index #3 of the tuple is the column title for the table specified.

Answer (score 0):

`str` is not valid for .columns(). Try with

u'Customers' or `unicode(tablename)`